# Gradle: How to remove class files after compilation

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to figure out how to remove java class files that I only needed for compile time in Gradle. In other words, I only want a certain class to be used for the compilation step, but to not be included in the jar package. In this case, I'm talking about a BuildConfig.java class that I need to remove from my library project because I have another one defined in my application project with the same namespace. Thanks in advance!

Comment: wouldn't gradle clean do the job?

Comment: or you could extend the clean task to delete the class file for BuildConfig.class

Comment: Sorry @chaitanya, I think I wasn't clear on the question so I added some clarification. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. This was my implementation:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
   String taskName = String.format("remove%BuildConfig", variant.name.capitalize())
   task "${taskName}" << {
      file("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${variant.name}/path/to/file/or/directory").delete()
   }
   variant.processJavaResources.dependsOn(taskName)
}
```

Basically, I went through all the library variants and added a task called "remove{variant}BuildConfig". And its job is obviously to delete the .class file in the ${buildDir}/intermediates/classes directory. Then you have to make sure the task runs before the processJavaResources task which is in charge of copying all java resources after compilation (so you have to make sure you remove the files/directories before that happens!)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude any class from a jar packaging. You may try this to include your gradle file.

```
jar {
    exclude "BuildConfig.class"
    // or
    exclude "**/BuildConfig.class"
}
```